# Flexslider works on Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox

Tags: firefox, slider, alignment, flexslider

I'm not sure why the homepage slider on my website works perfectly on Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox. It's using Flexslider. The alignment is completely off on Firefox. I'm really at a loss right now.

Here is the site:
http://www.sherwoodbedding.com/

I have already tried this CSS code for just Firefox, but that's a workaround I don't want to launch with.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .full-homepage-slider ul.slides li {
        margin: 0 !important;
        float: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: So what part doesn't work, exactly?  A clear description of what you expected to see and what you see instead would really help...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem myself!

Finally worked out that it was because I'd applied (a 'bottom') margin to the flexslider class (.flexslider) in the CSS to shift content underneath the slider down - somehow in Firefox it was shifting the image down from the top instead causing the alignment problem.

SOLUTION: Remove any margin values that apply to: `.flexslider` (or any `div` container)

If you still need elements around the slider to move in relation to it, use `padding` on the `div` container instead of `margin`.